# .htaccess Redirect 403 not works

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to block the following url in .htaccess by redirect to 403 or 301 redirect to site url

> https://www.sitename.com/a/manage_blog
>
> https://www.sitename.com/index.php/a/manage_blog

In .htaccess, I wrote like

```
RewriteRule ^(index.php/?)?a/manage_blog  - [L,R=403]
```

It works on when the url has index.php, without the index.php, it wont works

I also tried the following

```
RewriteRule ^(index.php/?)?(a/?)?manage_blog  - [L,R=403]
```

Please guide me to solve the problem.

Comment: Try this rule as your top most rule: `RewriteRule ^(index\.php/)?a/manage_blog(/.*)?$  - [F,NC]`

Comment: @anubhava It's works fine. could you please explain in details

Comment: @anubhava Put your answer in answer section, for accepting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this rule as your top most rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(index\.php/)?a/manage_blog(/.*)?$ - [F,NC]
```

- `(index\.php/)?` optionally matches `index.php/` at the start.
- `a/manage_blog(/.*)?$` matches `a/manage_blog` followed by any optional string before end of input.
- `[F,NC]` will return 403 (forbidden) status is request URI matches this pattern.

Comment: Please explain what issue I made it

Comment: Most likely you didn't use this rule as top most rule in your .htaccess and other rules were executing before this rule

Comment: Thank you very much